# Help in an exercise on Markov chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I'm doing an exercise on Markov chain and I'm in doubt if I'm doing it right.

Below is the image in the question and soon after my response.
[MY QUESTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPciZ.jpg).

In the first item my answer was as follows

$$0.08333333, 0.2132867, 0.3868007, 0.2226836, 0.145979$$

Where I multiplied the matrix $P$ by $P$ and made $\alpha P^2$,

My doubts are as follows. The sum of my lines is not $1$. And when you tried trying to do item $B$ by doing the matrix $P ^ {100}$ for example this is going up the values ​​pro infinito.

I would like help if I am doing something wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a thought, I'm not sure, but could it be you need to perform $P^2\alpha^T$ maybe, where $\alpha^T$ is the transpose of $\alpha$ (i.e. a column vector rather than a row vector). PS - it would have been better if you set your question out rather than referring to a picture. That could be why the down votes...

Comment: Part b should be done by computing the left eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$, not by simply computing large powers of $P$. I can't tell why your $\alpha P^2$ sums to something so far off from $1$.

Comment: @Antinous No, the matrix is left-stochastic so the answer to part a is indeed obtained by computing $\alpha P^2$.

Comment: @Ian But 0.08333333 + 0.2132867 + 0.3868007 +0.2226836 + 0.145979 is not 1, 
is this right?

Comment: @LucasFreitas No, I didn't notice until I actually put it in a calculator that the error is quite large (the sum is something like 1.05), so you made some mistake (probably a data entry mistake).

Comment: @Ian ah yes, I see, so convert to the form $P=Q^{-1}\Lambda Q$, where $\Lambda$ is diagonal, so that $P^n=Q^{-1}\Lambda^nQ$, where $\Lambda^n$ is much easier to compute since it's diagonal.

Comment: @Antinous In fact you don't even need to fully diagonalize, you just need to compute one eigenvector and then use a theorem to note that the contribution from all the other eigenvalues will decay.

Comment: @Antinous I am confused. I made the matrix P ^ 2 and then multiplied by the alpha. This is wrong?

Comment: @LucasFreitas according to Ian, yes i was wrong on that idea. Compare what you're doing with this simple example; should give you a bit of confidence in what you're doing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Examples_of_Markov_chains#A_simple_weather_model. You may need to use the diagonalisation method above for large powers... i.e. limit as time tends to infinity. And if rows don't sum to 1 then check you haven't made an arithmetic error or copied down the matrix/vector incorrectly. You may want to use  CAS such as Mathematica to verify you're calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably missed some number at the time of computing

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct, but you’re right to have doubts about your result. If the row sums (and the sum of the elements of the resulting distribution) are not all equal to $1$, then you’ve made a computational error somewhere. With this particular $\alpha$, $\alpha P^2$ is just the last row of $P^2$. The only element that’s incorrect is the first one, so recheck your work for the lower-left element of $P^2$. Most of the first column of $P$ is zero, so there’s not a lot of room for making errors there.

For the second part, there’s no need to diagonalize $P$. From the wording of the problem, you can safely assume that there *is* an unique steady-state distribution and so as Ian mentioned, you just need a left eigenvector of $1$. That is, solve the equation $\mathbf\pi(P-I)=0$ with the additional condition that the elements of $\mathbf\pi$ all lie in $[0,1]$ and sum to $1$. You can, of course, find *any* solution and then normalize it to meet this condition.